# Predicting rating values of unrated items in a given dataset

Tags: java, prediction, rating

I am somewhat new to data mining, and I am working on a improving diversity in recommendation system.

I have collected data sets from movielens, and I am planning to predict rating values of unrated movies. So, I would like to know which data mining tool or any algorithm that  could provide the functionality for my issue. Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Look it up https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code

Probably you'll need to use a form of supervised filtering and feed you model your training dataset according to which it'll learn to rate the new data that you put in.